# Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape....... found shape=(None, 143)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, data-science

I am a beginner in machine learning and I am trying to train a model with nltk and tensorflow. But I get the following error when I run my program. I understand the problem. it seems that the shape of my list does not pass but I do not know why and I do not find any relief. I specify that I use a list of lists with different sizes. Need help please I need to understand, solve and move forward
code and error:

[image]

I am trying to train a model with nltk and tensorflow. But  it seems that the shape of my list does not pass but I do not know why and I do not find any relief. I specify that I use a list of lists with different sizes.

github code:
https://github.com/maeltoukap/whatsapp-chat-bot

Comment: I'm using python 3.10.X

Comment: The worst thing you can do is post a screenshot of text, from where people cannot copy or search for your text.

Comment: So what should i do?

Comment: Copy and paste the actual code here. And don`t forget proper formatting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you are missing two reshape steps. You need to add the lines

```
train_x = np.expand_dims(train_x, axis=1)
train_y = np.expand_dims(train_y, axis=1)
```

after you define `train_x` and `train_y` (so after line 67 in your picture). Your input shape is then the shape of your first training example, so change `input_shape: train_x[0]` to `input_shape: train_x[0].shape`. Also change the number of neurons in your last dense layer. Currently you have in your last layer `Dense(len(train_y[0])...`. You need to change that to `Dense(30, ...)`. Then you should be good.

The complete code would look like this:

```
random.shuffle(training)
training = np.array(training, dtype=object)

train_x = list(training[:, 0])
train_y = list(training[:, 1])
train_x = np.expand_dims(train_x, axis=1)
train_y = np.expand_dims(train_y, axis=1)

print(len(train_x))
model = Sequential()
# model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=113, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=train_x[0].shape, activation='relu'))
# model.add(Dense(128, input_shape=(len(train_x[0])), activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
model.add(Dense(54, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.5))
# model.add(Dense(113, activation='softmax'))
model.add(Dense(30, activation='softmax'))


sgd =  SGD(learning_rate=0.01, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])



hist = model.fit(train_x, train_y, epochs=200, batch_size=5, verbose=1)
```

Comment: i tried it but now i have this error: ``Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 113, 2), found shape=(None, 113, 143)``

Comment: I tried ``input_shape: (113, 143)`` but getting ``Shapes (None, 113, 30) and (None, 113, 113) are incompatible``

Comment: It is really hard to understand how your data looks like. What are you trying to put in (how do you training examples look like)?
And do all your training examples have the same shape?

Comment: Can i send the github link?

Comment: I'm trying to add the code here but i don't know how

Comment: Send the link please

Comment: https://github.com/maeltoukap/whatsapp-chat-bot

Comment: The trainning code is in the ``training.py`` file

Comment: Updated my answer, it should work now.

Comment: Are you interested in being my teacher or mentor? I am a beginner in machine learning and I would really like to become an expert

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251687/discussion-between-noltibus-and-mael-toukap).